# How do I adjust opacity of an "image as a plane" in Version 2.90.1?

Tags: image

I want to adjust the opacity of an image overlapping another image.
For example, in this image, I have a car overlapping an airplane.
How do I get that same effect in blender?
[image]
All the tutorials I've found are very outdated, the UI has changed so much at this point, they can't be followed. Do I have to setup some kind of crazy thing in the shader editor, or is there some simple opacity slider I am overlooking?
I managed to get the image added with transparency, I just can't figure out how to adjust the opacity so I can see through the image.
[image]
*Edit* Finally was able to adjust the opacity without removing the transparency using the suggestions provided, adding a second Mix Shader and Transparent BSDF (for a simple effect, this was not easy for a beginner):
[image]

Comment: Hello :). Simply adjust the opacity of your *AP_SHADELESS* nodegroup. You can mix it with *Transparent BSDF* and use the fac slider.

Comment: @JachymMichal I'm now able to adjust the opacity of the image, but the background is no longer transparent, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hey :). Not what I had in mind. Keep the alpha plugged as before, but add another *mix* and *transparent* shader right after your nodegroup.

Comment: @JachymMichal that did the trick! This seems way more difficult than it should be, I guess because it's just meant more for 3d objects?

Comment: Well, Blender's node editor is a bit of an overkill for simple tasks like that :). I feel your pain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When selecting your image plane, navigate to the image section of the properties side bar and click on the transparency button to enable it, then adjust the opacity to your desired value.
[image]

Alternatively, if you are using the add-on version of images as planes, and still wish to see your image in the final render, you can modify your shader like this, and use the "fac" slider to adjust transparency.
[image]

Comment: I don't see that as an option

Comment: I am using the add-on version of images as planes, is there some other way to do this?
How did you get the menu option in your first picture?

Comment: @NoRestarts I Just noticed that you are using the images as planes add-on, as opposed to the built-in feature under add-->image-->background. I would recommend using this method if you just want to use a reference image, but if you wish to have your image show up in the final render, use the add-on instead. I added a second option for how to adjust transparency using the add-on in my post.

Comment: I am trying to learn how to morph 1 image into another, but I need to make one image slightly transparent so that I can line up the shape keys. I'm trying to use this tutorial, but it is so outdated, the UI looks so different: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sNjE2EVYSq0

Comment: @NoRestarts I just watched that tutorial, and it is extremely outdated, even for the time it was made, I think It might just be easier for me to make a new tutorial, I'll update you on when it is finished.

Comment: That would be amazing! Thank you so much!

Comment: @NoRestarts I finished making the tutorial, and I decided to make it public so that others can learn from it to: https://youtu.be/ifgQyd49hj8

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much @SupaKoopaTroopa64